# Python's threading.enumerate function returns an unexpected results

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-multithreading, undetected-chromedriver, seleniumbase

I am using `multithreading` to run multiple `Selenium` drivers at the same time. Every driver has an individual thread. When I have 70 driver instances (`ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=70)`) `len(threading.enumerate())` must return 70 + 1 (Including `MainThread`), isn't it ? When process is running after some time `len(threading.enumerate())` returns wrong result (80, 90 threads). I am using `seleniumbase / undetected-chromedriver`. Maybe these libraries are creating an extra threads ?

```py
import concurrent.futures
import threading
import time
from seleniumbase import Driver


# Pseudocode
def run_driver(driver, url):
    try:
        driver.get(url=url)
        print(url, len(threading.enumerate()))  # Wrong result
        time.sleep(10)
    except Exception as exc:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()


urls = ['https://google.com' for i in range(70)]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(urls)) as executor:
    for url in urls:
        driver = Driver(uc=True, headed=True)
        executor.submit(run_driver, driver, url)
```

Comment: I think you've answered your own question "Maybe these libraries are creating an extra threads"

Comment: From what I understand Selenium's package for Python is using the subprocess module which does use threading for some things.

Comment: @CtrlZ @Abdul Aziz Barkat You are right guys. I ran `ps aux | grep python` and there are many processes created by `seleniumbase` library... So 1 `process` = 1 `thread` (minimum). I would say, this is the answer on my question. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `driver.quit()` in the `finally` block, otherwise the driver only gets quit in your script if there's an exception. I made some updates to the code, and added `sys.argv.append("-n")` so that the thread-locking is handled correctly in SeleniumBase UC Mode when patching the driver, etc.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import threading
import time
from seleniumbase import Driver
import sys
sys.argv.append("-n")


def run_driver(url):
    driver = Driver(uc=True)
    try:
        driver.get(url=url)
        print(url, len(threading.enumerate()))
        time.sleep(3)
    finally:
        driver.quit()


urls = ['https://seleniumbase.io/demo_page' for i in range(8)]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(urls)) as executor:
    for url in urls:
        executor.submit(run_driver, url)
```

Comment: How many processes are created by `seleniumbase` ? Let's say, I created 100 threads from my script, how many would be an extra from `seleniumbase` side (Meaning processes + threads) ? What's the logic behind the scenes ? When I run `driver.close() driver.quit()` `seleniumbase's` additional processes + threads are killed immediately ? Regarding your advice, I always do `driver.close() driver.quit()` in the `finally` block.

Comment: `driver.close()` is for closing the current tab. `driver.quit()` actually quits the process. From my script, there are 9 processes: The original, plus the 8 that were spun up via `concurrent.futures`.

Comment: @ifdef14 to be clear the extra threads you see are not the threads that belong to the processes, `threading.enumerate()` won't get you threads of other processes. The extra threads you see are potentially spun up by the `subprocess` module for the purpose of communicating, etc. with the other processes.